# JSX render a letter initial button wrapping a set of buttons that starts with the same letter

Tags: arrays, reactjs, for-loop, mapping, jsx

Got two arrays: one that has letter initials (allergiesInitials) and the other that has some words (allergies). I want to render a letter button and then a bunch of buttons (from the array of words) that starts with the same letter as the first button but I don't know how to alternate them:

```
{allergies.map((allergy, i) => {
   for (const letter of allergiesInitials) {
      if (letter === allergy.nombre.charAt(0)) {
         return (
            <div>
              <button>{letter}</button>
              <TestButton key={i} id={i} allergyName={allergy.nombre} fnSaveAllergyInfo={saveAllergyInfo} allergyID={allergy._id}/>
            </div>
           )
         }
      }}
   )}
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution would be to map the letters, and then filter the array of `allergies`, and take only allergies with name that starts with the letter. Then you can map the filtered allergies and render their buttons:

```
{allergiesInitials.map(letter => (
  <div>
  <button>{letter}</button>
  {allergies.filter(allergy => allergy.nombre.toLowerCase().startsWith(letter))
    .map(allergy => (
      <TestButton
        key={allergy._id}
        id={allergy._id}
        allergyName={allergy.nombre}
        fnSaveAllergyInfo={saveAllergyInfo}
        allergyID={allergy._id}
        />
    ))
  }
  </div>
))}
```

If there are many allergies, filtering the entire array for every letter might be inefficient. In that case, it's easier to group the allergies by letters first, and then render them in one go:

```
const allergiesByLetters = allergies.reduce((acc, allergy) => {
  const letter = allergy.nombre.charAt(0).toLowerCase();

  if (!acc.has(letter)) acc.set(letter, []);
  
  acc.get(letter).push(allergy);

  return acc
}, new Map())


{allergiesInitials.map(letter => (
  <div>
  <button>{letter}</button>
  {allergiesByLetters.get(letter)
    .map(allergy => (
      <TestButton
        key={allergy._id}
        id={allergy._id}
        allergyName={allergy.nombre}
        fnSaveAllergyInfo={saveAllergyInfo}
        allergyID={allergy._id}
        />
    ))
  }
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: It totally worked with your first approach. Thanks so much.